# IE8 is slow for loading pages, how to make it faster?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, pageload, page-load-time

This wordpress/bootstrap website I have been working on is slow in IE8 for page load times, but fairly quick in all the other browsers I have tested on. I have used W3 total cache and minified all my css and js files. I am not sure what else to do. Can someone help?

http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/euU8TD/www.firstbase.ca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

You can speed up loading time a lot by minifying your javascript. An article that I found useful in the past for speeding up loading time is http://apmblog.compuware.com/2010/08/25/top-10-client-side-performance-problems-in-web-2-0/

Comment: Just to verify that not all of your javascript is minified, see the method body of `addTwitterBSClass(thisObj)`